# Theorem 122. of Hardy's Theory of Numbers.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

The following is from the *Theory of Numbers* by Hardy, et al. 
[image]
Obviously, the number of roots of (8.2.1) is *at least* the product of the numbers of roots of the separate congruences (8.2.2). But what if this type of solution to (8.2.1)? : Let $d$ be a solution to $f(x) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod m})$ such that $f(x) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod m_r})$ for one $r \in {\{1,2, \dots k}\}$ and *not* a solution to none of the $f(x) \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod m_i})$ for $i \ne r$. Then $d \equiv c_l  \ (\text{mod m_r})$ and congruent to other solutions of other modules so is not one of those types in the set of elements like (8.2.3). So why the number of roots of (8.2.1) **equals** the product of the numbers of roots of the separate congruences (8.2.2)?

Comment: You can find many worked concrete examples [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+combination+root+mod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is that every root mod $m$ of $f$ gives a unique set of solutions mod $m_i$ and vice versa. You see how to go from the first to the second. To go the other way you have to take $k$ solutions $d_1, ... , d_k$ such that $f(d_i) = 0 \text{ mod }m_i$. (Note the size of this set is equal to the product of the number of solutions to each $f(x) = 0 \text{ mod } m_i.$) Pick the unique number $d$ mod $m$ such that $d = d_i$ mod $m_i$ for all $i$ (this is the Chinese remainder theorem, and can be done by the euclidean algorithm).

For example, if we want to find the roots of $f(x) = x^2 + 3$ mod $12,$ we write $12 = 4 * 3,$ so $m_1 = 4, m_2 = 3.$ We solve $x^2+3 = 0$ mod $4,$ getting solutions $1$ and $3.$ We solve $x^2+3 = 0$ mod $3,$ and find $x=0$ is our only solution. Note that $x=1$ does not solve the original problem mod $12.$ However if we find a number that is $1$ mod $4$ and $0$ mod $3$, like $9,$ then we find: $$9^2 + 3 = (-3)^2 + 3 = 9 + 3 = 0 \text{ mod }12.$$  The second solution comes from finding a number that is $3$ mod $4$ and $0$ mod $3,$ ie $3$ mod $12.$